# Set an elements height depending on viewport width and height

Tags: jquery, window, size

Sry if my title is not correct at all.

Well, I got this code, to make my "section" equal to height device:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  function setHeight() {
    windowHeight = $(window).innerHeight() -80;
    $('.top-banner').css('min-height', windowHeight);
  };
  setHeight();

  $(window).resize(function() {
    setHeight();
  });
```

});

It's working fine, and all that, but also I'm using Navbar Bootstrap, and when is a mobile o desktop, navbar changes the height. I put "-80" on my js and it works when 768< but when is a mobile, I need to be "-50". So, I think I shoul do it with some "if else" but not sure how to. I am not an old user, so, I'll be glad if can you tell me what code do I need, and, how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what sizes of screen width to add to the if/else condition, as I can't fully understand your question, but maybe this is enough to help you along the way:

```
function setHeight() {
    var vw = $(window).width();
    var vh = $(window).height();
    if (vw <= 768) {
        $('.top-banner').css('min-height', vh-50 + 'px');
    } else {
        $('.top-banner').css('min-height', vh-80 + 'px');
    }
};
```

Comment: I found the way as the same time xD

http://jsfiddle.net/gtdh4yfg/
that's what I did. But,thank you so much. :) Now I will consider set "var" to make it easier